# Align checkbox to the right side in LinearLayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make some text views with checkboxes in LinearLayout. I want for result like this:

```
TextView           Ckeckbox
TextViewwwwww      Ckeckbox
TextV              Ckeckbox
```

But currently I have this:

```
TextView  Checkbox
TextViewwwww  Checkbox
TextView  Checkbox
```

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this xml gives me same result:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"/>
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `layout_weight` attribute on your `TextView` only to automatically designate the `TextView` to fill any space which the `CheckBox` does not occupy. For example, the following will set your checkboxes to the end (provided they have no text associated with them) and then lets the TextView fill the rest of the layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Additionally, you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as `fill_parent` is deprecated.

Comment: @Andrew_Z If this has worked for you, you should mark the answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) so others can benefit from the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_gravity="right"` instead of `gravity="end"` if you're working with `vertical` layouts.

Your `CheckBox` tag should look like:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
```

**EDIT:** On `horizontal` layouts, try `layout_weight="1"`, that will make both of your elements fill half of the layout space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ipdemo.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layout weights and try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="wdjhwdjwo"/>

    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkItem"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **layout_weight** attribute to achieve the effect

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*So horizontally both the views will be occupying half of the screen size.* You could adjust layout_weight to achieve the desired outcome.

There maybe other ways to do this, but I think this method is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

check the following use  android:layout_weight="1" in both view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

          android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Checkboxes lined, but not to the ride it lined to the center